# Is it correct to state that a sum series converges as long as the partial sums do as well?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence, summation

I can't understand that statement i heard during a math course with the fact that the partial sum's series of the natural numbers don't converge and the fact that according to Euler and Riemann the infinite sum of the naturals equals -1/12....

By the way, how come the latter result doesn't violate numbers theory: I suppose that if you sum natural numbers you can't obtain an element essentialy different from them as i believe a rational number is...I mean they're outside the naturals group! does it matter at all?

Comment: By *definition*, the infinite series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges if the **sequence** of partial sums $$\left\{\,b_m:=\sum_{n=1}^m a_n\,\right\}$$ converges (finitely, that's it).

Comment: $$1+2+3+ \cdots = - \frac{1}{12}$$ is not true in the usual sense.

Comment: @Crostul Does the "unusual" sense have anything to do with sequences of real numbers ?

Comment: This series has been treated many times on this site and has [its own Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), which appears to answer your questions (as far as these are clear). To avoid repetition of things that have already been written many times, perhaps you could focus your question on what parts, if any, of the Wikipedia article you don't understand?

Comment: Keep in mind that $$1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$$ is **only** true in the context of the Riemann Zeta function, not in regular context, like with number theory.

Comment: No where do we **EVER** say $1+2+3+\cdots$ converges to $-1/12$, and to say it is even equal, we must be careful.

Comment: @joriki I've seen the wikipedia article but that doesn't clear my mind on the subtject I posted, because it goes beyond the mere definition of the series, the zeta function and the rest....I'm trying to get to the details and see if I am understanding all the concepts...that's why i'm relating it with series theory and more

Comment: @Ethan1987: That's terribly vague and broad. Please ask a specific question.

Comment: @joriki the question actually is specific. now that someone answered something it's developing

Comment: @Ethan1987: You don't have to take my word for it; three other downvoters also think the question is badly phrased. Four downvotes is quite a lot on this site.

Comment: @joriki Yeah, I expected such a receivement when daring to try to ask on such an annoying matter for an educational help community as this is...I guess i'll have to apologise for seeking help in the site when things i've looked couldn't fullfill my curiosity or surpased my understanding on the matter or even weren't enough for all my questions. I feel terrible for having to make you waste your time on commenting on my question to another people. Also i must be ashamed of asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of infinite series, an infinite sum is defined as the limit of the partial sums, and so, as you stated, the infinite sum converges if and only if the sequence of partial sums does, as they are the same thing.  So, in this context, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$ diverges.

To say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n = \frac{-1}{12}$ is a little misleading, to say the least.  This is often quoted in this form for its shock value, because we mathematicians like to keep an air of mystery about our work (mostly so that laypeople think we are smart ;-) ).

Note that we can write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{-1}}$.  This may look like a strange thing to do, but in your study of series you will no doubt come across the Harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$, and the related series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ for any $p > 0$.

The Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(s)$, is an extension of this last generalisation, where the value $p$ is replaced by a complex number (and changes its name to $s$).  Now the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges whenever $s$ is a real number greater than $1$.  The zeta function, $\zeta(s)$, is what is called an analytic continuation of this function to the complex plane excluding $s = 1$ - it is a well-defined function taking values for all $s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 1 \}$ such that $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ whenever $s$ is a real number bigger than $1$.

It just so happens that $\zeta(-1) = \frac{-1}{12}$, which leads to the oft-quoted statement that is not technically correct.  It is incorrect because $\zeta(s)$ is not defined as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ for all values of $s$.

Finally, one should note that this zeta function is very important in mathematics; the famous Riemann Hypothesis concerns (non-trivial) zeroes of this function, and is deeply tied to the distribution of prime numbers, among other things.

EDIT: As mentioned by @joriki, there are other approaches that lead to the value of $\frac{-1}{12}$, and are covered in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Summability).

ADDENDUM: It seems some additional remarks on analytic continuations might be helpful.  While the Riemann zeta function itself is too complex (pun intended) for me to explain well here, I will take a simpler, and yet hopefully still illustrative, example.

Given non-negative integers $n,k \ge 0$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ can (dare I say should) be defined as the number of subsets of size $k$ of an $n$-element set.  Some elementary counting gives the formula $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!} = \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (n - j)$.

Now when you look at this formula, there is no reason why $n$ should be an integer.  Indeed, we can define a function $f(x) = \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (x - j)$, which is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (or even $x \in \mathbb{C}$, should you so wish).  Indeed, this is a polynomial, which is about as nice as functions can get, and it has the property that whenever $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, $f(x) = \binom{x}{k}$ counts the number of subsets of size $k$ of an $x$-element set.

We can plug other values into this function too.  For example,
$$ f(-1) = \frac{1}{k!} \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} (-1 - j) = (-1)^k. $$
However, we cannot say that a set of size $-1$ has $(-1)^k$ subsets of size $k$; that is patently nonsense.  The equivalence between that definition of the binomial coefficient and this polynomial function is only valid for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$.

Similarly, the zeta function $\zeta(s)$ is equal the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ when $s \in \mathbb{R}_{> 1}$.  However, it extends that series to a wider domain (namely $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{1\}$) to give a function with very nice analytic properties - this is what is meant by an analytic continuation.  It so happens that $\zeta(-1) = \frac{-1}{12}$, but it is incorrect to claim that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{-1}} = \zeta(-1) = \frac{-1}{12}, $$
since the second equality above is not valid for $s = -1$.  As is easy to show, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n$ diverges instead.

Comment: I think this answer places too much weight on the analytic continuation, which is just one of several ways of arriving at the "sum" $-\frac1{12}$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Summability)).

Comment: Given that the question referenced Euler and Riemann, I think the focus on the analytic continuation is fair.  I'll add the reference to the other approaches though.

Comment: @Shagnik Concerning the Zeta-function : Not only is it undefined at $x=1$, the limit for $x\rightarrow 1$ does not exist either. So, why does the analytic continuation have the property that the limit exists ?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for pointing that out, that was sloppy of me.

Comment: Yes, I saw the wikipedia article and also the numberphile videos on youtube. There they say something quite different, they say Euler used all real s values and Riemann used all comlex ones, so s=-1 is interpreted as a singularity....so am I to understand that you mean the result is technically incorrect just because you say the analitic continuation is defined in a certain way? meaning that that's just a formality but nothing stops me when using all complex plane for s values. Or is there something more? I can't see why the equality doesn't stand alone, how come a result depends on context?

Comment: I don't understand those expressions. Please develop on that, the things you said I've seen but can't make a definitive answer from them...
Maybe there's more on analitical continuations that i'm not catching...

Comment: @Ethan1987 I've added an example to try to explain what I mean - I hope that helps.

Comment: @Shagnik That was indeed illustrative, but would you indulge me with an opinion on how numberphile people present the matter (just in the case you saw the video)...would you consider it being plainly wrong, or am I misinterpreting them?, I can't come to other impression different from them saying the naturals series converges and it's a fact everyone should get accostumed to. If you shan't do this just forget it and accept my humble thanks.

Comment: PS: Could there be many "schools" or "many respected opinions" about the matter? I know mathematics is not about opinions at all, but please understand that it's a feeling that someone as ignorant in the subject as me can't help to co with, i guess it's just residual or yet inevitable excepticism or suspicion...i never seem to get to the point of feeling secure even if receiving a valid answer when it comes to the limits of my knowledge

Comment: PS 2: If you feel my questions bother you in any way or that I'm not worth your answers please restrain from responding, i prefer not being answered at all, not to mention you don't have to and the fact that i've already granted you my vote for giving me some explanation. I never intended to impose nothing or even dare to appear inteligent to anyone (I don't find any pleasure in such activities as some people do), i just felt confused and asked for help...this is just to clear intentions, no harm intended, and never would.

Comment: @Ethan1987: I haven't seen the video, I'm afraid. There is a well-established definition of convergence of a series, and as per that definition, the series diverges. That is not a matter of opinion or subject to debate. There are some different ways in which one can manipulate the sum to get something that can be said to be equal to $-1/12$, as covered by the Wikipedia article, but those are not compatible with the theory of convergence of series, so to simply say $1+2+3+...=-1/12$ without further explanation is wrong.

Comment: @Ethan1987: I think the reason your question attracted such a negative response was that it is a vague open- ended question about a topic that has been dealt with in depth before. It would have been better to narrow down exactly what was causing your confusion, and explain why other resources (Wikipedia, other questions and answers on this site) were not resolving the issue.